# Can't catch lasting focus on specific recyclerview item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus

I'm trying to set focus on specific item in recyclerview like:

```
recyclerview.scrollToPosition(positionX);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I can see for a milisecond that I get focus on desired item and then it automatically changes focus to the first element. Maybe some wild guesses what is causing this / an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

why are you calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Just call the scroll to position. calling notify ask recyclerview to update its views

```
recyclerview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition()
```

Comment: Well, without notifyDataSetChanged() I do not get a focus change.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, you need to call scroll to on layout manger of recyclerview

Comment: Nothing changed :/